# Displaying report - ic3ready is not defined

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I work on displaying a IcCube report in a web application that runs on a server.

This is a code snippet we use:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8282/icCube/doc/ic3-report/app/reporting/js/loader/ic3bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">



    var ic3root = "http://localhost:8282/icCube/doc/ic3-report/app/";
    var ic3rootLocal = "http://localhost:8282/icCube/doc/ic3-report/app-local/";

    var options = {

        root: ic3root,
        rootLocal: ic3rootLocal,

        callback: function () {

            var options = {
                dsSettings:{
                    userName:"",
                    userPassword:"",
                    url: "http://localhost:8282/icCube/gvi"
                },

                mode:ic3.MainReportMode.REPORTING,
                hideTopPanel: true,

                noticesLevel:ic3.NoticeLevel.ERROR,


                report: {
                    name: 'shared/asda'
                }
            };

            ic3.startReport(options);
        }
    };

    ic3ready(options);

</script>
```

When I run this in a standalone HTML wile it works fine but when I try to run in on on a server embedded inside my application I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ic3ready is not defined
at <anonymous>:43:9
at DOMEval (jquery.js:82)
at domManip (jquery.js:5782)
at jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery.js:5918)
at jQuery.fn.init.eval (jquery.js:6012)
at access (jquery.js:3976)
at jQuery.fn.init.html (jquery.js:5979)
at Object.link (angular-route.js:1198)
at eval (angular.js:1294)
at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:10255)
```

I use Wildfly 10 application server with Java EE and Angular 1.5.

Any help is really appricitated.

Comment: Is the js file ic3bootstrap.js loaded (check with the debugger), looks like as it's not the case as the function is defined there.

Comment: As we can see, it is. http://i.imgur.com/8CXYra1.png

Comment: Strange as the function is defined in this file, there are no other errors. Are you sure the file is loaded before executing the js code ? (did you tried to add a breakpoint) ?